# Gibbs sampling for t distribution with location and scale paameter

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, markov-chains, bayesian

I have observations $X_{1},..,X_{100}$. Further $X_{i} \sim t(\mu, \sigma, \nu)$, where $\mu$ is location parameter, $\sigma$ is scale parameter and $\nu$ is degree of freedom. I want Gibbs samples from the posterior distribution $P(\mu, \sigma, \nu|X)$. How do I develop the sampler?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: To be clear, are you asking how, for a given set of $(\mu, \sigma, \nu)$ you can use Gibbs sampling to generate a sample for the corresponding Student-t distribution, OR that given some set of samples $\{X_i\}$, you want to sample the posterior distribution for the parameters $P(\mu, \sigma, \nu | \{X_i\})$ to learn about their possible values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that what you want to do is sample from the posterior distribution for the distribution parameters $P(\mu, \sigma, \nu | \mathbf{X})$, where $\mathbf{X}$ is your set of observations $\mathbf{X} = X_1, X_2, ..., X_{100}$, then you would go about it in the following way:

**Constructing the posterior**

First we need to construct the joint-likelihood of all your observations as follows:

$$
P(\mathbf{X} | \mu, \sigma, \nu) = \prod_{i} P(X_i | \mu, \sigma, \nu),
$$
where $P(X_i | \mu, \sigma, \nu)$ is the student-t density.

Now we can define the posterior through Bayes' theorem:
$$
P(\mu, \sigma, \nu | \mathbf{X}) = \frac{P(\mathbf{X} | \mu, \sigma, \nu) P( \mu, \sigma, \nu) }{P(\mathbf{X})}
$$

**Gibbs sampling algorithm**

First, choose some initial guess for the parameters $\theta_0 = (\mu_0, \sigma_0, \nu_0)$.

The update $\theta_n \to \theta_{n+1}$ is performed as follows:

1. Sample $\mu_{n+1}$ from $P(\mu | \sigma_n, \nu_n , \mathbf{X})$
2. Sample $\sigma_{n+1}$ from $P(\sigma | \mu_{n+1}, \nu_n , \mathbf{X})$
3. Sample $\nu_{n+1}$ from $P(\nu | \mu_{n+1}, \sigma_{n+1}, \mathbf{X})$
4. Let $\theta_{n+1} = (\mu_{n+1}, \sigma_{n+1}, \nu_{n+1})$

This is the Gibbs sampling update.

**Parameter conditional distributions**

Clearly this requires you to sample from the 1D parameter conditional distributions. It may be that the conditionals can be derived analytically for the sudent-t distribution for some specific choices of prior, but this is not necessary - you can still evaluate them numerically.

As an example of how you derive conditionals, here is the procedure for $P(\mu | \sigma, \nu , \mathbf{X})$. The product rule allows us to write
$$
P(\mu, \sigma, \nu | \mathbf{X}) = P(\mu | \sigma, \nu, \mathbf{X}) P( \sigma, \nu | \mathbf{X}),
$$
where $P( \sigma, \nu | \mathbf{X})$ is a marginal distribution given by
$$
P( \sigma, \nu | \mathbf{X}) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(\mu, \sigma, \nu | \mathbf{X}) \, \mathrm{d}\mu.
$$
Solving for $P(\mu | \sigma, \nu, \mathbf{X})$ we can write
$$
P(\mu | \sigma, \nu, \mathbf{X}) = \frac{P(\mu, \sigma, \nu | \mathbf{X})}{P( \sigma, \nu | \mathbf{X})} = \frac{P(\mathbf{X} | \mu, \sigma, \nu) P( \mu, \sigma, \nu)}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(\mathbf{X} | \mu, \sigma, \nu) P( \mu, \sigma, \nu) \, \mathrm{d}\mu}
$$

To actually draw samples from the conditional distributions, typically you would use either rejection sampling or 1D metropolis-hastings MCMC.

**1D Metropolis-Hastings MCMC**

Suppose you want to sample values of a variable $x$ some 1D conditional distribution $P(x | I)$:

> Metropolis-Hastings update: $x_n \to x_{n+1}$
>   1. Sample a proposed update $\hat{x}$ from a normal proposal distribution $\mathcal{N}(x_n, \sigma_x)$
>   2. Sample a random value $t \sim \mathrm{Uniform}(0,1)$
>   3. if $t < P(\hat{x} | I) / P( x_n | I)$, we accept the proposal and set $x_{n+1} = \hat{x}$, else repeat steps 1 & 2 until a proposal is accepted.

Here $\sigma_x$ is the proposal width, and for this approach to be efficient we want to choose $\sigma_x$ such that about 50% of proposed steps are accepted. Most implementations of MCMC have an internal mechanism to adjust $\sigma_x$ towards an optimal vlaue.

Given that you are new to this area, you may still have some questions - if you edit your question to ask them I'll do my best to answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support! Could you please give me more insight how can I sample using Metropolis-Hastings algorithm? More precisely what are the target distributions and the proposal distributions in this case? Or even better is that possible to find some priors the analytical solution of these marginals? Which way gives the better results?

Comment: @JamesGreen It may be possible to get some analytical answers for conditionals with certain priors, but it won't really help you if you are interested in using the 1D metropolis MCMC. I'll add some extra info to my answer on the MCMC method shortly.

Comment: @CBrowman thank you very much for metropolis algorithm. However which proposals can I use for $\sigma$ and $\nu$? I can not apply normal distribution, as $\sigma > 0$ and $\nu > 2$.

Comment: @JamesGreen So while using normal proposals for $\sigma, \nu$ is not ideal, we can still do it by having a prior distribution which equals zero in cases where $\sigma < 0$ or $\nu < 2$. That way, if a proposed step violates the allowed value bounds, the posterior will equal zero, and the step will always be rejected.

Comment: @CBrowman OK, I wanna have a uniform prior for $p(\sigma) = 1/A, if \sigma \in (0, A)$ and $p(\nu) = 1/(B-2), if \nu \in (2, B)$. And the proposals $N(\sigma_{i-1}, \epsilon_{\sigma}^{2})$ and $N(\nu_{i-1}, \epsilon_{\nu}^{2})$. What will be the target distribution for $\sigma$ and $\nu$?

Comment: @JamesGreen yeah those priors look good - the target distributions in both cases are just the conditionals that you need to sample from, so after sampling $\mu_{n+1}$, get $\sigma_{n+1}$ from $P(\sigma | \mu_{n+1}, \nu_n , \mathbf{X})$, and then $\nu_{n+1}$ from $P(\nu | \mu_{n+1}, \sigma_{n+1} , \mathbf{X})$.

Comment: @CBrowman thank you again for your input! Is the mixing of 1D Metropolis inside of Gibbs sampling standard technique? I am wondering whether the ergodic theorem still holds or do I have to prove it for this particular case?

Comment: Does the order in Gibbs sampling matter?

Comment: @JamesGreen As far as I know it doesn't - I seen some implementations that randomise the order, but many just repeat an arbitrary ordering over and over.

Comment: @JamesGreen I believe this is a fairly common approach, and because of that I *assume* the ergodic theorem holds but honestly I'm not sure.